# Как ускорить Hibernate?

Tags: oracle, jpa, hibernate, java-ee, orm

Есть web java app используещее Hibernate. Проблема в том что слишком медленно работает сохранение в БД в новых объектов. Есть ли какие-нибудь способы или настройки, которые могут повысить производительность?

Comment: Профайлер запускали? Может у Вас не сохранение, а преобразование в строку тормозит или доступ к базе данных, которая лежит на другом конце света.

Comment: а че все сразу накинулись на человека, ни для кого не секрет что любой орм фреймворк это еще те тормоза

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate является не очень производительным, если у тебя большая нагрузка, то лучше юзать Spring JDBC или MyBatis. Ну а если у тебя идёт долгое добавление в локальную базу данных при одном пользователе, то тогда конечно что-то не правильно настроил и читай мануал...

Answer (score 3):

Прежде чем ругаться на то, что тормозит ОРМ, следует тщательно просмотреть что и как вы делаете и попрофайлить.